# json_encode not working

Tags: javascript, html, json

i have a problem with a polling script im trying to setup...the script works great on my localhost but when i transfer it to the live server i trows out a few bugs...my localhost version of php is 5.3.8 and the live server is 5.2.13....the poll wroks interms of updating the database. I narrowed it down to a problem the json_encode...its not calling the javascript, iv read trough loads of posts but cant find the answer...here is some snippet of code

```
    include_once ('db_connect.php');
    include_once ('functions.php');

    if ( isset($_POST['poll']) and isset($_POST['option'])){

        $poll_id = intval($_POST['poll']);
        $option_id = intval($_POST['option']);

            add_vote( $option_id,$poll_id );
            setcookie('poll_'.$poll_id, 1, time() * (60 * 60 * 5),'/');

            exit( json_encode(array('results' => results($poll_id))));
    }
```

and here's the javascript

```
       $("img", form).remove();
        //set the new options Percentages
        $.each(data.results, function (option, value) {
            $("p#option_" + option).find("span").show().css({
                width: 0,
                opacity: 0
            }).animate({
                width: value + "%",
                backgroundColor: getColorForPercentage(value / 100),
                opacity: 1
            }, "slow", "swing", function () {
                $("p#option_" + option).find("em").text(value + "%").fadeIn("slow");
            })
        });

    }, "json");
    return false;
```

its absolutly craking me up....
what if tried so fare...
to put 
     exit(); after the json_encode...

ANy help would be greatly apreciate...

Thanks

Comment: Try something like `var_dump(json_encode(array('results' => results($poll_id)))); die();` and look what is coming out

Comment: Are you sure, json_encode is not working ?

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: big thanks for the quick reply:) still no joy:(...you can check the script at opinionfreaks.com....could it be the version of php???

Comment: im positive its the json_encode...iv gone trough the whole script and narrowed it down to this, you can see it in action from the link mentioned above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the following warning and any extra output.

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Expiry date cannot have a year greater then 9999 in <b>/content/Hosting/o/p/opinionfreaks.com/web/vote.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
string(53) "{"results":{"1":46.7,"2":10,"3":26.7,"4":10,"5":6.7}}"
```

OR you can do `error_reporting(E_ERROR);` but still its `<br />` printing.

Consider following too:

```
setcookie('poll_'.$poll_id, 1, time() + (60 * 60 * 5),'/'); // its + not *
```

Comment: that this line on code setcookie('poll_'.$poll_id, 1, time() * (60 * 60 * 5),'/');

Comment: that is number of seconds, you can choose any. Code speaks :) firebug is a great and handy tool.

Comment: hi Dev...im way ahead of ya but its telling me 'Vote up requires 15 reputation :(...ill get back to ya'...im only new to this site...big big thanks again...you the man:)